# Please prove distinguishability given a non-perfectly secure cipher

Tags: classical-cipher, perfect-secrecy

I'm trying to prove that a perfectly secure cipher yields indistinguishability. I already know and can prove that a perfect cipher => indistinguishability by the following proof:

\begin{align}
\Pr(Enc(m_1) = c) = & \Pr(C = c | P = m_1) \\
 & = \frac{\Pr(C = c \land P = m_1)}{\Pr(P = m_1)} \\
 & = \frac{\Pr(C = c) | \Pr(P = m_1|C = c)}{\Pr(P = m_1)}\\
 & = \frac{\Pr(C = c) | \Pr(P = m_1)}{\Pr(P = m_1)}\\
 & = \Pr(C = c)\\
\end{align}

Please help me prove indistinguishability will yield a perfect/secure cipher (indistinguishability => perfect cipher) which is the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

The proof in the question is not about the *perfect secrecy* $\implies$ *indistinguishability*. It is about proving that; if *perfect secrecy* than we have $$ Pr[C=c| M=m] = Pr[C=c]$$ Also, we don't need the $\wedge$ step, just use *Bayes' Theorem* directly. The reverse (1) of this also true that is if we have $$ Pr[C=c| M=m] = Pr[C=c]$$ that we have *perfect secrecy*.

Now assuming that we have indistinguishability. That is; for every probability distribution over the message space $\mathcal{M}$ and every $m_0,m_1 \in \mathcal{M}$, and for every $c \in \mathcal{C}$;

$$Pr[C=c| M=m_0] = Pr[C=c | M=m_1] $$ we will show that we have prefect secrecy.

Since, the equation holds for ever $m_0,m_1$ we can say $Pr[C=c| M=m_0] = Pr[C=c | M=m_1] = p$ (2).

Now, write $Pr[C=c]$ as;

\begin{align}
Pr[C=c] & = \sum_{m\in\mathcal{M}} Pr[C=c | M=m] \cdot Pr[M=m] \\
 & = \sum_{m\in\mathcal{M}} p \cdot  Pr[M=m] \\
 & = p \sum_{m\in\mathcal{M}} Pr[M=m] \quad\quad\quad\quad \\
 & = p \\ 
 & = Pr[C=c| M = m_0]  \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad//(\text{use }2)
\end{align}
we have;

$Pr[C=c] = Pr[C=c| M = m_0]$ ,

now use (2);

$$Pr[M=m | C=c] = Pr[M = m_0]$$ therefore, *indistinguishability* $\implies$ *perfect cipher*